# How to select a service to use to begin making investments?

Tags: stocks, investing, trading, etf, ireland

I'm looking to make a small investment in stocks. I like the idea of ETF's and since I'm based in Ireland I'm considering using Davy : http://www.davyselect.ie/our-services/self-invest.html Is this the most direct way (removing the middle man) of investing in stocks?

What other kinds of services should I consider ? Since I'm based in Europe (Ireland) are there other questions I need to be asking myself with regard to what platform I should use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the most direct way (removing the middle man) of investing in stocks?

There ain't no middleman, like the old days. But if you take it literally, the broker is the middleman.

> What other services should I consider ?

Use a comparison website or trawl the web for opinions and reviews. Pay particular importance to how client money is safeguarded, the financial health of the service provider, which regions you can trade, commissions, inactivity fee, read between the lines of their agreement before you sign on the dotted lines and if they provide other services too and of what kind. And if you want to walk away, what will be the consequences and if they provide a grace period or not.

> what platform I should use ?

Which platform you use, should be dependent on your requirements and on your requirements alone. Not what I use or what the seller is offering. Don't go for gimmicky offerings, but check how it will benefit you now or in the future.

Comment: " the broker is the middleman." so there is no way to remove the broker ?

Comment: @Adrian - Why are you worried about the broker ? They aren't going to skim you just like that. But do check them diligently. There are EU regulations which regulate the brokers and the services they provide. There is no failsafe guarantee, but you will be fine. The cost benefit of removing a broker is too much and is ill advised.